# how to avoid of using nested lapply in R?

Tags: r, performance, function, lapply

I am seeking efficient alternative for nested lapply, I think using nested structure is not appreciated in R community. Can anyone propose possible ideas, or approach to avoid of using nest lapply in custom function?

Here is quick reproducible example:

## simulated Data

```
a <- data.frame(
  start=seq(1, by=9, len=18), stop=seq(6, by=9, len=18),
  ID=letters[seq(1:18)], score=sample(1:25, 18, replace = FALSE))
b <- data.frame(
  start=seq(2, by=11, len=20), stop=seq(8, by=11, len=20),
  ID=letters[seq(1:20)], score=sample(1:25, 20, replace = FALSE))
c <- data.frame(
  start=seq(4, by=11, len=25), stop=seq(9, by=11, len=25),
  ID=letters[seq(1:25)], score=sample(1:25, 25, replace = FALSE))
```

## function that I used nested lapply, but want to avoid this:

```
a.big <- a[a$score >10,]
a.sml <- a[(a$score > 6 & a$score <= 10),]
a.non <- a[a$score < 6,]

a_new <- list('big'=a.big, 'sml'=a.sml)
tar.list <- list(b,c)

test <- lapply(a_new, function(ele_) {
  re <- lapply(tar.list, function(li) {
    out <- base::setdiff(ele_, li)
    return(out)
  })
})
```

## objective:

avoid of using nested lapply, to find its efficient alternative. I mean to find better representation for its output which must be easy/fast to reproduce, and allow fast/easy downstream computation. Is there any general approach to do this?

How to avoid of using nested lapply in `test`? Can anyone propose possible ideas to get through this issues ? Thanks

Best regards:

Jeff

Comment: Did you try to run your example code in a fresh R session? Also you should describe what you are trying to do vs just paste code.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Yes, I tried, but if I used nested lapply in my custom function, it returns something that I don't expected. above code is simulated based on result of my functions. I am seeking general strategy for replacing nested structure for dealing with big data.frame objects. What's general approach for avoid this issues?

Comment: @Jimbou: I can accept all possible output except list-like object. Could you elaborate your possible approach as answer here ?

Comment: @user88911 You can try `Map(setdiff, a_new, tar.list)`

Comment: @Jimbou: but it wasn't mapped in full scale, seems it only return first parallel mapping, while rest was dropped. Any better idea? Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want. But if you like `setdiff` of all combinations of both lists, then you can use something like this:

```
# all combinations
a <- expand.grid(seq_along(a_new), seq_along(tar.list))
a
  Var1 Var2
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    1    2
4    2    2
# apply over all combinations setdiff row-vice 
apply(a, 1, function(x, y, z){ setdiff(y[x[1]], z[x[2]])}, a_new, tar.list)[1:2]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   start stop ID score
2     10   15  b    21
3     19   24  c    12
6     46   51  f    23
9     73   78  i    15
10    82   87  j    19
11    91   96  k    25
13   109  114  m    11
16   136  141  p    17
17   145  150  q    18
18   154  159  r    24


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   start stop ID score
5     37   42  e     9
14   118  123  n     8
15   127  132  o     7
```

Using double `[[]]` brakets gives you a cleaner output of only one list.

```
apply(a, 1, function(x, y, z){ setdiff(y[[x[1]]],z[[x[2]]])}, a_new, tar.list)

[[1]]
   start stop ID score
2     10   15  b    21
3     19   24  c    12
6     46   51  f    23
9     73   78  i    15
10    82   87  j    19
11    91   96  k    25
13   109  114  m    11
16   136  141  p    17
17   145  150  q    18
18   154  159  r    24

[[2]]
   start stop ID score
5     37   42  e     9
14   118  123  n     8
15   127  132  o     7

[[3]]
   start stop ID score
2     10   15  b    21
3     19   24  c    12
6     46   51  f    23
9     73   78  i    15
10    82   87  j    19
11    91   96  k    25
13   109  114  m    11
16   136  141  p    17
17   145  150  q    18
18   154  159  r    24

[[4]]
   start stop ID score
5     37   42  e     9
14   118  123  n     8
15   127  132  o     7
```

Comment: Is that possible to get exactly same output format that what I did if we are using your approach? I think using expand.grid is very smart things to do and possibly yield my expected output. However, how can I put your output in the matrix or data.frame? I want to let the vector with same dimension put together. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user88911 Use an ordered `a` like this `a <- a[order(a$Var1),]`?

Comment: Just perfect answer. Thanks again for your big help here.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
outd <- function(ele_, li) base::setdiff(ele_, li)
mapply(outd, a_new, tar.list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

> mapply(outd, a_new, tar.list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
$big
   start stop ID score
1      1    6  a    12
6     46   51  f    20
8     64   69  h    24
9     73   78  i    13
10    82   87  j    11
12   100  105  l    19
14   118  123  n    16
15   127  132  o    18
16   136  141  p    22
17   145  150  q    23
18   154  159  r    14

$sml
  start stop ID score
2    10   15  b     9
7    55   60  g    10
```

## Edit

In the previous case `mapply` applies the function to pairs of the lists elements.

If we take the ideia from `outer` to expand both lists, we get (not sure if will work in other cases):

```
bY <- rep(tar.list, rep.int(length(a_new), length(tar.list)))
bX <- rep(a_new, times = ceiling(length(bY)/length(a_new)))
mapply(outd, bX, bY, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

> mapply(outd, bX, bY, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
$big
   start stop ID score
1      1    6  a    25
2     10   15  b    23
4     28   33  d    14
7     55   60  g    19
9     73   78  i    20
10    82   87  j    21
12   100  105  l    13
13   109  114  m    12
14   118  123  n    22
16   136  141  p    15
17   145  150  q    18

$sml
   start stop ID score
6     46   51  f     9
8     64   69  h     8
18   154  159  r    10

$big
   start stop ID score
1      1    6  a    25
2     10   15  b    23
4     28   33  d    14
7     55   60  g    19
9     73   78  i    20
10    82   87  j    21
12   100  105  l    13
13   109  114  m    12
14   118  123  n    22
16   136  141  p    15
17   145  150  q    18

$sml
   start stop ID score
6     46   51  f     9
8     64   69  h     8
18   154  159  r    10
```

Comment: why using mapply did not return correct dimension of output like what I did? How can make that happen by using mapply? Thank you